# Disable Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) Notification in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, sfmc-business-unit

I am able to see the MFA Notification everytime after I enter my credentials and click on the Log In button wherein that notification is asking me to enable the MFA for my login to MC Org.

I don't want to enable MFA as of now. So wanted to disable that notification so that I will not be able to see that notification everytime I gets logged in to MC Org.

Please help to disable the MFA Notification...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the only way to disable this notification is to enable MFA. According to these [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_july_2020_setup_mfa.htm&type=5) this will become mandatory at some point

Comment: But I don't want to enable MFA as of now and wanted to disable this MFA notification instead... so is there any way to do it ?

Comment: It appears the only way to disable this notification is to enable MFA

Answer (score 0):

I've been in conversation with our account management on this. There is no way to disable the prompt and the team responsible for MFA will not remove the prompt.

Unfortunately you will just have to skip it until you are ready to implement it which is quite frustrating. We have hundreds of users and BUs, and are not ready to support MFA just yet for so many people.